# How can I pass NULL value in SqlData implementation for Long typed attribute?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I have loads of raw data (of type SqlData objects) coming in and trying to insert into Oracle using a user defined type created.

The problem is only for the records which has some Long attributes that are null.
I get a NullPointer exception for these records - as it tries to invoke toString on a null object.

Is there any way to write null values for Long column (in SQLOutput stream)?

I know this is possible by changing into String type, but I can not touch on the PL/SQL function as this is used from many places.

```
public classMyClass extends MyBaseType implements SQLData {

public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {

    stream.writeString(getSource());
    stream.writeTimestamp(getDtm());
    stream.writeString(getUniqueId());
    stream.writeString(getType());

    stream.writeLong(getResponseCode());
```

The last line causes NullPointer Exception when getResponseCode() is null.

Any idea how to handle this without changing the type (to String)?

The last option tried was,

```
private void writeNullPossibleNumber(SQLOutput stream, Integer intValue) throws SQLException {

    if (intValue==null) {
        stream.writeBigDecimal(null);
    } else {
        stream.writeInt(intValue);            
    }
}
```

The above solution is working properly.

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a81357/sampcod3.htm

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see `SQLOutput.writeLong` waits `primitive` `long`, but you seems try to provide the wrapper `Long`. In this case, of course, `null` can't be converted to any `primitive`.

So, or just add `null check` before `writeLong`, or change the entire logic, if it isn't OK for you write nulls to DB at all.

Comment: You are right! - It expect primitive type. I think I am limited to adapt that, but the problem is that earlier implementation (using PreparedStatement setLong calls) it used to set NULL values. Some are id values, and I can't assume 0 in that places.

Comment: Good to know. So, add me reputation ;-)

Comment: Thanks!  You could improve the answer by indicating what to do if the null check indicates a null value.  Fortunately the OP updated his question with the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

You get `NPE` because of autounboxing. You should explicitly write null values, try something like this:

```
if (getResponseCode() != null) stream.writeBigDecimal(new BigDecimal(getResponseCode()));
else stream.writeBigDecimal(null);
```

Comment: I get the following - error code [17059]; Fail to convert to internal representation: ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation:

Comment: OK. Try this `stream.writeBigDecimal(null)`. Since any numbers are populated to the DB as NUMBER (especially for Oracle), it would be a workaround for `null` numbers.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I modified the answer. I didn't actually used `SQLOutput` and I looked in javadoc for a method to send null.

Comment: You can't have a two types mixed -- if(true) same type else same type. I tried that. But Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation:
        at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeNUMBER.toNUMBER(OracleTypeNUMBER.java:268)

Comment: @RajeshBalan Try using only `BigDecimal`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @ArtemBilan You were right, the only time BigDecimal is required when value is null. Otherwise it is supposed to be as the same type. I have modified the post. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can either of the following options:

- Explicitly use NULL for the null value (use an if statement to select NULL or the toString)
- Eliminate the column from in the insert if the value is null

Something like the following helper class might be useful to you.

```
public class DatabaseHelper {
private static final String CNULL = "NULL";

static public String fixValue(Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return CNULL;
    } else {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that I need to touch on the Server contract to support this. Like I said, earlier implementation was using PreparedStatement setLong call, where null also was permitted. Some values are IDs, and is these are null I can't assume this to be 0, as in my previous implementation this was set to be NULL